# Link with native libraries in different NDK modules

Tags: android, android-ndk, linker, shared-libraries

I have a modularized application architecture with 3 module layers.

A core library module at the bottom and an application library module and my application on top of it.  Each builds it's own native shared library. But not only the java code but also the C++ code in them also depends on each other.

So my "application.so" must link to "library.so" and "core.so" and on the other hand "library.so" must link "core.so"  just like you expect from any layered architecture.

I can see in the file system that the shared so libraries all end up in the same build directory but i can't find a way to make them link each other. "find_library" is not going to work. And just naming them in "target_link_libraries" is not going to work either.

EDIT: With

```
buildFeatures { 
    prefabPublishing true
}

prefab {
    infosqueezer {
        headers "src/main/cpp/include"
    }
}
```

i was able to generate an aar. But i'm not able to include it into the the other module. Both debug and release aar's are  generated in the "library/build/output/aar/" directory. The modules are in the same project so i just need to reference by file somehow.

I'm using

```
implementation project(path: ':library')
```

but it does not pickup the so file. Also the AAR does not contain any "libraryConfig.cmake" or "library-config.cmake" that the find_package command would need to find the link library.

---

Also the whole prefab process seems to be terrible. I just want to split the in project source code to reduce compile time and dependencies. Prefab is adding so much and surely a good idea to distribute indpendent libraries but overkill for internal libraries.

All i need is just a way to reference the generated "library.so" file in another module.

I know it's Android but do they really make everything so terrible complicated?

Comment: You might want to expand on how your configuration doesn't fit with [Native dependencies with AARs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/native-dependencies?buildsystem=cmake#native_dependencies_in_aars)

Comment: @MorrisonChang  thank you for the link, this might be the answer. Unfortunately i don't understand it. It's very under documented. How do i use prefab?  I understand the cmake part of it but not how prefab is setup.  Any step by step tutorials?

Comment: As prefabs are new: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/02/native-dependencies-in-android-studio-40.html your best bet might be the sample project https://github.com/android/ndk-samples/tree/main/prefab

Comment: Thanks, wow this is 20 days old sample code. And different from the documented gradle options mentioned elsewhere. So it's still in development and not API stable. My warning lights are on, i had enough projects in my life bleeding to death when using bleeding edge early adopter things. So what was the previous way to set NDK dependencies among modules?

Comment: Sorry for sending you down the prefab path. For internal libraries look to https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/prebuilts

Comment: I ended up using `implementation files('...\...\mylibrary-release.aar')` to gain access to the Kotlin/Java classes (`.kt` file classes), then a separate `externalNativeBuild { cmake { path file('../../MyOtherProject/myotherproject/src/main/cpp/myotherproject/CMakeLists.txt' ... )` to make available the C++ headers and body code. A straight AAR prefab should work but I just couldn't get it to link to the `.so` files in the prefab in the end. A total pain in the arse ! The downside of this side is you can't just disseminate your AAR, but it does work for my own dev to build my APKs. Nightmare !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no supported way to depend on native libraries from other modules in the same project with `externalNativeBuild` (at least in part because it will lead to worse build performance, see below).

As described your project should have a single gradle module for its native code if you want the best build performance (and want to be on a supported usage model).

If you really want these to be separate, the only way to do this that works with AGP is for them to be separate *projects*. I don't think you should do that.

> Also the whole prefab process seems to be terrible.

This isn't what it's meant for. Screw drivers make terrible hammers.

> I just want to split the in project source code to reduce compile time and dependencies.

Splitting gradle projects into more modules usually makes compile times worse, not better. I can't think of any reason that it would improve build performance for native projects, and it can easily make it much slower since invoking CMake is not cheap and splitting modules up multiplies that cost.